# After upgrading Laravel Nova from 3 to 4 all actions cause a Recursion Detected error when encoding Actions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

Having upgraded from Laravel from 8 to 9 and Nova from 3 to 4, whenever I try to include an Action in a Resource it's unable to encode the data because it believes that it's recursive, but I can't see what it considers to be recursive. Here is what I believe it's trying to encode:

```
array (
'actions' => 
    Laravel\Nova\Actions\ActionCollection::__set_state(array(
       'items' => 
        array (
            0 => 
      App\Nova\Actions\TestAction::__set_state(array(
         'name' => NULL,
         'component' => 'confirm-action-modal',
         'withoutActionEvents' => false,
         'withoutConfirmation' => false,
         'onlyOnIndex' => false,
         'onlyOnDetail' => false,
         'showOnIndex' => true,
         'showOnDetail' => true,
         'showInline' => true,
         'actionBatchId' => NULL,
         'runCallback' => NULL,
         'thenCallback' => NULL,
         'confirmButtonText' => 'Run Action',
         'cancelButtonText' => 'Cancel',
         'confirmText' => 'Are you sure you want to run this action?',
         'standalone' => false,
         'responseType' => 'json',
         'modalSize' => '2xl',
         'modalStyle' => 'window',
         'seeCallback' => NULL,
         'meta' => 
        array (
        ),
         'job' => NULL,
         'connection' => NULL,
         'queue' => NULL,
         'chainConnection' => NULL,
         'chainQueue' => NULL,
         'chainCatchCallbacks' => NULL,
         'delay' => NULL,
         'afterCommit' => NULL,
         'middleware' => 
        array (
        ),
         'chained' => 
        array (
        ),
      )),
    ),
     'escapeWhenCastingToString' => false,
  )),
  'pivotActions' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Pivot',
    'actions' => 
    Illuminate\Support\Collection::__set_state(array(
       'items' => 
      array (
      ),
       'escapeWhenCastingToString' => false,
    )),
  ),
  'counts' => 
  array (
    'standalone' => 0,
    'resource' => 1,
  ),
)
```

And here is the relevant part of the stack trace:

```
{
    "message": "Recursion detected",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "file": "/var/www/patina-api-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php",
    "line": 93,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/patina-api-laravel/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/JsonResponse.php",
            "line": 59,
            "function": "setData",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/patina-api-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php",
            "line": 33,
            "function": "__construct",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\JsonResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/patina-api-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php",
            "line": 101,
            "function": "__construct",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/patina-api-laravel/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Controllers/ActionController.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "json",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

I got this from Logging at key points in the `setData()` function of `Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse` and I believe that the issue occurs when it calls `json_encode()` on the above data on line 89.

The `TestAction` is a blank `Action` class generated by Nova's Artisan command after having upgraded to v4; it does nothing.

I expect the response generated by the call to get Nova actions to be encoded.

Initially, I believed that this was being caused by a circular relationship between our `User` and `Role` models since in my initial attempts to print the data to the log file it was implying it was trying to encode instances of `User` and `Role` that were parent and child of each other. I have tried severing that circular relationship in the model classes. I don't believe that this is still relevant given the above information but I'm mentioning it anyway in case I'm wrong.